# Incorrect SOLR synonym expansion

Tags: solr

I'm trying to track down a weird SOLR SynonymnFilterFactory issue.  In Solr 4.6.1 and 4.7 with this configuration:

> ```
>     <fieldType name="text_buggy" class="solr.TextField">
>         <analyzer type="index">
>             <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
>             <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" 
>                 synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
>             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
>         </analyzer>
>         <analyzer type="query">
>             <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
>             <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
>         </analyzer>
>     </fieldType>
> ```

With this synonyms.txt entry:

> wbc,white blood count

Field analysis output for the string "`due to elevated wbc patient was placed on medication`" in solr admin shows the following:

```
ST | due | to | elevated | wbc         | patient         | was         | placed | on | medication
SF | due | to | elevated | wbc | white | patient | blood | was | count | placed | on | medication
```

But why is it not something more like below?  I'm getting some strange search results because of the above:

```
ST | due | to | elevated | wbc                         | patient | was | placed | on | medication
SF | due | to | elevated | wbc | white | blood | count | patient | was | placed | on | medication
```

**UPDATE:**
After reading [this SOLR bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3390) I did find that by changing my  to LUCENE_33 I get a better result (probably the one that I remember getting in the past):

```
ST | due | to | elevated | wbc                                         | patient | was | placed | on | medication
SF | due | to | elevated | wbc | white | white | count | blood | count | patient | was | placed | on | medication
```

Comment: Yes, multi-word synonyms are a pain in Solr. Read this post: http://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr/

Comment: BTW, what unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: Thanks, I actually have read that and wanted to move that direction eventually.  My issue is that at one point I think I was getting my desired results above and it seems to have regressed somehow.  The first issue I encountered was that a search for 'white blood count' no longer matches (without some proximity matching) since they are not next to each other anymore.  I also get some really bizarre hit highlight results.